# What is the '\oops' in 'I\errorcontextlines=100 \oops' and where should they be placed in TeX file?

Tags: errors, tex-core

At the bottom of page 34 of **The TeXbook**, there is

> If you use TEX format packages designed by others, your error messages may involve many inscrutable two-line levels of macro context. By setting \errorcontextlines=0 at the beginning of your file, you can reduce the amount of information that is reported; TEX will show only the top and bottom pairs of context lines together with up to \errorcontextlines additional two-line items. (If anything has thereby been omitted, you’ll also see ‘...’.) Chances are good that you can spot the source of an error even when most of a large context has been suppressed; if not, you can say ‘I\errorcontextlines=100 \oops’ and try again. (That will usually give you an undefined control sequence error and plenty of context.) Plain TEX sets \errorcontextlines=5.

The original tex file is

```
\hrule
\vskip 1in
\centerline{\bf A SHORT \ERROR STORY}
\vskip 6pt
\centerline{\sl by A. U. Thor}
\vskip .5cm
Once upon a time, in a distant
   galaxy called \"O\"o\c c,
there lived a computer
named R.~J. Drofnats.

Mr.~Drofnats--- or ``R. J.,'' as
he preferred to be called---% error has been fixed!
was happiest when he was at work
typesetting beautiful documents.
\vskip 1in
\hrule
\vfill\eject
```

As the first character of `I\errorcontextlines=100 \oops` is `I`, so I guess it should be entered after `\input filename` when the error shows. But what is `\oops` here and why should it be added here? And after input `I\errorcontextlines=100 \oops` the log file doesn't contain more information than not inputing `I\errorcontextlines=100 \oops`.

Comment: \oops is simply a placeholder for the erroneous command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If this control sequence is not defined, why doesn't it cause error?

Comment: You are not using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you enter after the `I` is executed by TeX. You enter it at the `?` prompt. So if you write
`I\errorcontextlines=100` TeX executes this assignment and continues
to work on your document; probably showing a follow-on error in
your text.

But if you enter `I\errorcontextlines=100 \oops` and if `\oops` is
undefined TeX stops a second time before it continues to read more
from your document as an undefined control word causes an error. So
you see more context of the first error, i.e., the error at which you
entered `I\errorcontextlines=100 \oops` and you can add more `I`
commands if the then shown context gives you more insight.

If you do not see any change in the context then TeX has given you all
the context it has. But, for example, if you have several nested macros and
the innermost contains an error you see more context.

```
\errorcontextlines=5 \errorstopmode
\def\one{this one has an \ERROR!!!}\def\two{Here we call \one;}
\def\three{and here \two;}\def\four{now call \three;}\def\five{and \four.}
\def\six{Let's try to call \five.}\def\seven{The main macro calls \six.}

\seven
and another \ERROR.
\bye
```

Comment: So, should `\errorcontextlines=100` be input not `\errorcontextlines=100 \oops`? And why did Mr. Knuth add `\oops` here? With your code, having and not having the `I\errorcontextlines=100` will output the same log file.

Comment: @Y.zeng No, please look carefully. The log files are different as with `\oops`
one more error is reported. It's a trick or technique if you want to fix a text interactively. Of course you must be in `\errorstopmode`.

Comment: For what to use `\oops` to cause another error?  It seems there is no need to do that.

Comment: Have you executed the code with `\errorstopmode`? It's a significant
difference if you enter `I\errorcontextlines=100` with or without `\oops` after TeX stops and shows you the ?-prompt. In the first case
you see the next error caused by the last word of the file, the undefined control word `\ERROR`. In the second case you see the complete context of the error caused by `\seven`.